# Using verification emails for files

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-email, flow

So I am setting up a request sheet on a sharepoint in the form of an xlsx file. I can't use a list since the file has way too much information on it:
[image]

However, now I have the issue that I can't tell my flow which person to email the verification email to (different departments need different managers to get the email) and I can't set up the flow to email the person who made the request to let them know if the request was approved or denied.

I tried both an approval email and creating an approval event, neither allow for what I want, and the approval event won't even let me link the document to it.

I want the approval email to go the person in cell F7 and the response email to go the guy who edited it (SharePoint keeps track of this, but won't let you use that info, unless there is some code I don't know about)

Answer (score 0):

After playing with SharePoint for a few hours, I found out that it treats all of its libraries as lists, so when a new file is added, it treats that as a new item being added to a list.

Instead of sending a verification email when a file is changed, you can create an approval request with a link to the item. Then you can use the department information that the list saves to send the emails you want to send.